# jquery validation inconsistent before submit

Tags: jquery, validation

If you have a few required fields in a form and you fill all of them in and then gradually remove the text from them, some will show a validation message and others won't.

However, after you click submit then every time you empty a required field a validation message will show, which is better.

The issue is also happening on Jquery's own demo site http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Steps to reproduce:
1. enter some text into Firstname field
2. enter some text into Lastname field
3. focus out of the textbox
4. go back into Lastname field and delete the text with your Backspace button (not with the little x on the right of the field)
5. once all text is deleted in Lastname field validation message shows successfully
6. go into Firstname and delete all text with Backspace on your keyboard. 
7. once all text is deleted in Firstname the validation message does not show

Both Firstname and Lastname are required but validation shows only for one of them depending on which one you fill in first.

Ideally I would like to make this behavior consistent. I want this before-submit validation to happen all the time or not at all.

Any suggestions?